# Modifying the verbs for a file type in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, user-interface

In XP, you can change the verbs for a file type (open, edit, print, etc) via Tools->Folder Options. I can't find this in the Vista.

I know there's a programmatic/registry-matic way to do it, but how does one change this in the UI? Googling didn't help me much.

Comment: Besides the fact that I have no clue what you mean with "verbs", if you are asking about how to do it in a non "programmatic way" then this is not-programming-related and should be closed.

Comment: verbs are actions associated with a specific file type. windows uses it to figure out how to open, edit, print/etc a specific file type.  For example, double click on a file executes the "open" verb.    I'm asking for a non-programmatic way because it's way easier to test different verbs by changing them from a UI. I don't want to develop my own UI for doing this if it exists already.  But perhaps you're right and this should be closed.

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions, so if you're looking for non-programming ways of doing this, you probably want superuser.com. (Set User Defaults is the closest thing in Vista.)

Answer (score 0):

The File Types tab was removed in Vista (and later versions) and there is no real replacement, the closest you can get is the [Default Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#ui) section in Control Panel but it does not give you the same control over the verbs, you can only pick from a fixed list provided by the products installed on your machine.

There is also a 3rd-party program called [Default Programs Editor](https://defaultprogramseditor.com/) you could take a look at.